# When i zoom in/out the layout goes left/right .?

Tags: css, layout, zooming

When I zoom in/out my whole layout gets messed up. The layout goes towards the left/right. Here is my code . I have tried to work with a wrapper div and when I set margin left/right to auto it causes more damages to the elements in the layout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ON5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgzE6.jpg)

Comment: don't just screenshot cod

Comment: I wasn't allowed to paste the code , that is why i made a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1600px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked ,that you very much. Really appreciate it :)